# Visio 2016 Shape Protection cannot be removed

Tags: microsoft-visio-2016

I am using a Visio 2016 Cross-Functional Flowchart template - Vertical layout. I added two swimlane columns to the two columns in the prebuilt template, then resized them so that they evenly fit within the 11 X 8.5 in size. However, when I try to resize the Title column so that it is even across the page and does not overlap the right-most column, I end up either dragging the entire flow chart or I get the yellow "Shape protection,..." message in the 'Cross-Functional Flowchart - cannot edit column width' image. I tried the following things to be able to resize the Title column, but none work.

Also, is there a way to delete/remove this Title column altogether?

1. Ungroup - I get the yellow "Shape protection,..." message.
2. Edit width in Size & Position to 8 in. - width flips back to 6.25 in.
3. In Developer tab > Shape Design > Protection, remove all protection. I still cannot edit the width.
4. I went to the Home tab > Editing group > Layers > Layer Properties, and Lock is not checked.

[Cross-Functional Flowchart - cannot edit column width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/941e4.png)

Comment: Did you [unlock](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/prevent-or-allow-changes-to-shapes-e65decf4-0eed-4fd6-a7d9-b286abcbc7eb) the shape?

Comment: @Ramhound I went to the Home tab > Editing group > Layers > Layer Properties, and there is no lock to clear.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I did the steps you hyperlinked the word 'unlock' to. I listed it as #3 on the list of things I tried prior to posting the issue.

Comment: Yes; I realize you might have tried that, but you have to understand, your screenshot is literally indicating it's still enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I grappled with this problem not too long ago. There's a couple possible solutions:

- Click on the Developer tab (if you don't have that, you'll need to enable it in File->Options->Customize Ribbon->Check the Developer Box and it will appear.)
- In the Developer tab, click on "Drawing Explorer". You'll see the file path of your Visio document at the top, and some folder icons below.
- Right-click where you see the document's file path. Choose "Protect Document" from that menu.
- Uncheck the box that says "Shapes" next to it.

---

If that didn't work, try this:

- Click on the Developer tab (if you don't have that, you'll need to enable it in File->Options->Customize Ribbon->Check the Developer Box and it will appear.)
- Right click the flowchart and select "Show Shape Sheet". (You won't see this if you don't have the Developer tab enabled.)
- You'll see a big gray window appear. Right-click anywhere in the dark gray and select "View Sections".
- You'll see a pretty large list of check boxes. Click "None", then check "Protection" and click OK.
- You'll see a bunch of fields called "LockWidth, LockHeight, ... " etc. Change all their values from 1 to 0. This should allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is at below link.  In short :

1. add developer to ribbon (File --> Options)
2. select shape, click Developer in ribbon --> Protection --> unselect height and width

https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-format-text-to-fit-a-shape-in-microsoft-word